# Woocommerce woocommerce_order_status_processing trigger only in user side

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I would like to ask you guys if this is possible in Woocommerce hooks

the hook I'm using is this one,
woocommerce_order_status_processing

I want this hook only to be called in user side after payment, which is works ok but in the admin if I change the oder status, this hook is also triggering, can I disabled my custom hook in admin and will run/trigger only for the user side?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'order_extracode' );
function order_extracod( $order_id) {
.....
}
```

the above code is the function and hook I added, I  tried !is_admin() but it is not working, and still processing this function in Admin Orders

thanks (TIA)

Answer (score 6):

This hook will be executed every time there's a statu change.
What you can do is to decide if you want to execute the code in the front or in the Dashboard.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'order_extracode' );
function order_extracod( $order_id) {
  if( ! is_admin()){
     // Your code here
  }
}
```

The only conditional tag to detect if you are in the dashboard or not is the is_admin()

Answer (score 1):

WooCommere cannot tell the difference between who is triggering the `woocommerce_order_status_processing` action.

If you want something to happen when the user completes payment, you could try the `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook in `abstract-wc-order.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `current_user_can()` function to determine the whether the hook can be executed or not, like this

```
if( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
   //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: If the administrator wants to use the front end this solution will not trigger the hook, better stick to conditional tags that separate the admin and the front end.